# Как называется специальность выпускника РГГУ (см.)?

Tags: падежи

*Факультет истории искусства РГГУ* - это факт, проверять не надо.

Спорим с выпускником, кем его обозвать в популярном тексте.

Он говорит: историк искусств. Я: историк искусств**а**.

> Историк искусств, как любой другой исследователь, бо́льшую часть
>   своего времени проводит в наблюдениях, а затем занимается расшифровкой
>   увиденного.

Гугл отзывается и на то и на другое - как же ж жить?

Comment: А как им в дипломе пишут? По идее именно "историк искусств" - правильнее. Доктор филологических **наук**. Аналогия далекая, но смысл тот же. Искусство - искусству рознь.

Comment: https://www.ucheba.ru/for-abiturients/speciality/55278 - здесь, думаю, правильно, сайт профессиональный.

Comment: И на этом сайте разночтения. *Историков искусства выпускается немного*, *Специальность  «История искусств»*...

Comment: Да смотрите по названиям специальностей, а не то, что они от себя написали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы как историк такого специалиста назвал **Искусствоведом** или **культурологом**, в зависимости от специализации.

Если же требуется подчеркнуть, что специалист именно по истории искусств, то **историк искусств**. Искусство здесь понимается как декоративное, а не любой артефакт человеческого происхождения,поэтому множественное число уместнее.

Comment: Культуролог не в тему совсем, это совершенно про другое. Искусствоведение - это более общее название, а история искусств относится к искусствоведению.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрев по разным местам, почти убедился, что в большинстве документально подтвержденных или исторически закрепленных источников в этом и подобных сочетаниях - множественное число.

Например.
"Могила Стасова в Некрополе **мастеров искусств** в Санкт-Петербурге."
[Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).

И это при том, что в большинстве текстов в вики - в единственном числе.

Или форма "заслуженный деятель искусств".

*Хотя, если текст не претендует на большую официальность, то "историк искусства", наверное, тоже допустимо. Но мне меньше нравится даже в бытовом применении. Может, въелось с "младых ногтей"*.